# Wordpress plugins conflict

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Who has encountered and knows the solution to the problem?

There is a conflict between the plugins on the Wordpress site with the installed theme Topkie and plugins:

Akismet Anti-Spam (deactivated and therefore has no effect) v 5.1

Breadcrumb NavXT v7.2.0

Contact Form 7 v5.7.5.1

Envato Market v2.0.8

Google XML Sitemaps Generator v1.3.5

Health Check & Troubleshooting v1.6.0 was before the problem, does not affect it

IndexNow v 1.0.1

MC4WP: Mailchimp for WordPress v4.9.3

One Click Demo Import v3.1.2

Redux Framework v4.4.0

Elementor v3.1.12.1 - conflicts with RSElements v1.0.0. If I disable it, the site loads, but the content inappropriately suffers

Elementor Pro v3.7.3

RS Framework v1.0

RSElements v1.0.0 if disabled - site loads but content suffers unacceptably. Conflicts with Elementor v3.1.12.1

Slider Revolution v6.4.11

Yoast SEO v20.4

The problem does NOT appear on all pages of the site, but only those that were originally created by Topkie Theme.

I expect to load website